# How to populate a combo box in C# using an SQLite database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, combobox

I am currently trying to add data from an SQLite database and this is where I am at. The amount of data values in the combo box is correct, but it is not showing the actual data value, just ListViewItem: {}, please can someone show me where I have gone wrong.

```
SQLiteConnection techWorldConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\mwbel\OneDrive\Homework\A Level\Comp Science\NEA\NEA Program\NEA Example\bin\Debug\TechWorld.db"); // directs code to location of my database file
techWorldConnection.Open(); // goes to my database file and reads it

using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(techWorldConnection))
{
    SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select productName From Products", conn);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(dataset);
    foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.SubItems.Add(row["productName"].ToString());
        OrderProductList.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
techWorldConnection.Close();
```

Comment: @zaggler thank you this fixed my issue, I was trying to convert the code from another part of my program that needed a list view so that was why it went wrong I suppose. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your question talks about a ComboBox, but you are working with ListViewItems.  You also don't mention what technology you are using (I believe both Windows Forms and WPF have there own versions of those controls). What's the type of OrderProductList.  If it is a Windows Forms combo box, then I believe that it will fall back and just call `ToString` on whatever it added to it (unless you get fancy).  If you call `ToString` on a type that does not override that function, you will get the type name (i.e., "ListViewItem")

Comment: @Flydog57 sorry, it was a Windows Forms App (.Net Framework) and was a ComboBox item, I tried the earlier suggested fix and everything is now working, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The amount of data values in the combo box is correct, but it is not showing the actual data value, just ListViewItem: {}

The issue is how you're adding the items, specifically this area:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
   lvi.SubItems.Add(row["productName"].ToString());
   OrderProductList.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

You don't need to loop the collection to get the data you need, you can fill a `DataTable`, set the `DisplayMember` on the `ComboBox` and finally set the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` to your datatable.

```
OrderProductList.DisplayMember = "productName";
SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select productName From Products", conn);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(table);
OrderProductList.DataSource = table;
```